# GDB remote protocol: how to analyse packets?

Tags: gdb, ecos

**I have:**

- A proprietary prototype ARM board (Cortex-M3 based) with eCos OS
- The board has the programmed RedBoot bootloader
- Serial line (RS-232)
- GDB debugger for ARM (arm-eabi-gdb)
- Host OS is Windows/Cygwin and/or Linux (actually, doesn't matter)

**Problem:** GDB debugger cannot connect to the target over the serial line.

**What I want:** is to sniff the packets of the GDB remote protocol in order to undestand whether the GDB stub on the target is alive and operating.

**Details:** RedBoot has an option to pass the target's control to the built-in GDB stub. I know that the RedBoot is alive, I can connect to it and send it commands over the serial line. [The RedBoot manual](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-latest/redboot/redboot-commands-and-examples.html) says that the switch to the GDB stub can be made by typing $ or + symbols (which are actually the prefixes of the GDB remote protocol packets). It seems to work for when I send those symbols the terminal dies. But I'm not sure if the RedBoot was compiled with the GDB stub support (don't ask me why :-)).

Then, when I try to connect to the board with my GDB debugger I get the following picture (on Windows):

```
(gdb) target remote COM3
Remote debugging using COM3
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
```

The port is correct, the baudrate as well. Actually the same output I get if I try to do the same with another serial port which is not connected with anything.

What I want to know is does GDB stub send back anything or not?

Intuitively I thought that probably

```
set verbose on
```

would help, but GDB manual says it has very a limited effect and my case is beyond it.

May be it is possible to compile GDB debugger with a macro which enables debug logging?

Comment: For those debugging GDB stubs for emulators, you likely also want to set `set remotetimeout 99999` on the client while you step debug the emulator in peace.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> What I want to know is does GDB stub send back anything or not?

Do this (before `target remote`):

```
(gdb) set debug remote 1
```