# Can one configure which (precisely) and how registers are displayed in gdb tui?

Tags: assembly, gdb, qemu, arm64, cpu-registers

I've been using aarch64-none-elf-gdb to debug ARM code running on qemu (all on MacOS Intel, but now M3) for some time now. It's been mildly unpleasant, but workable.

However, recently gdb has been displaying (apparently) random sets of registers: sometimes x0-x22 and some system registers, sometimes x0-x30 and SP etc., sometimes lots of system registers, sometimes only a few (and not the ones that have changed and which I need).

Now I'm using tui mode, which is mostly ok -- but there are *too many* registers (and the decimal value, which I don't want, is printed along with the hex value).

**Is there a way to configure which registers are displayed?**

For example, I want (in hex only):

x0-x30, SP, PC, ESR_EL1, ELR_EL1, FAR_EL1, CPSR, SPSR_EL1, CNTP_CVAL_EL0 etc.

but **not** :

ID_AA64ISAR5_EL1_RESERVED, VMPIDR_EL2 and most of the other **207** system registers!

Comment: You can choose the register group that's display in TUI mode with [`tui reg`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/TUI-Commands.html#index-tui-reg), you have to try and see if any of them are more useful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately the register groups aren't the solution: there are cp_regs (all system regs), general (general regs, ie. x0-x30, sp, pc and cpsr + **all** the system regs), system (empty), float (FP regs), vector and all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'd need to patch the Qemu code, in particular: the files in target/arm. Specifically, the dynamic generation of the XML target description.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415059/how-to-observe-aarch64-system-registers-in-qemu?rq=2) point the way...